# Open Sets and Closed Sets proof check

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

A subset of a set $M$ like the empty set may be open or closed like the empty set or the whole of $M$ itself.
So in order to show that a set is open or closed I should really check for both the set and it's complement whether they are open or closed right?

Comment: What do you mean by "checking a set"?

Comment: @Wojowu - edited

Comment: Once you know the set is open, you don't have to do anything with the complement - by definition, it's closed. Similarly, if you know the set is closed, then its complement is open by definition.

Comment: @Wojowu But I just gave an example??- the empty set is vacuously open. But by definition M is open also. So the empty set is both open and closed. Counterexample. So you should do this for every set to find out whether its open closed or both right?

Comment: If you prove that a set is open [respectively, closed], then you have also proved that its complement is closed [resp., open]. If you want to know if a set is *both open and closed* (such sets are called *clopen*), then yes you need to prove that about the set or prove that the set and its complement are both open or both closed.

Comment: @BrianO But my point is you may show is that it's open or closed with one check. And then it will follow that its complement will be closed or open. But you can't EVER tell when either is clopen until you check both. So why don't we ALWAYS check both the set and it's complement is closed or open to find out whether it may be open. For example I can deduce a open $\epsilon$- ball is open with triangle inequlity proof. But how do I know it's not ALSO closed i.e clopen without checking the complement?

Comment: There are other ways, without looking at the entire complement. For example, a set is closed iff it contains all of its boundary points. In the metric space case, the boundary of an open ϵ-ball consists of the elements at distance ϵ, the closure of the open ball is the closed ball. So you don't have to consider points at a distance of 10^10 x ϵ from the center.